# C++ template function - Compiler error: 'can not change from from const char* to int'

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction

I have a template function specified:

```
template<class T> void jsonParse(json_object* jobj, eParseWhat parseWhat, T &value) {
    ...

    if(parseWhat == PARSE_UID) {
        value = json_object_getInt(val);
    }
    if(parseWhar == PARSE_EMAIL) {
        value = json_object_getString(val);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now when I want to parse the `uid` of the json-object I call the method with an `int`:

```
json_object* obj = ...;
int uid = 0;
jsonParse(obj,PARSE_UID,uid);
```

But then a compile error occurs at the assignment in line:

```
value = json_object_getString(val);
```

Because of the call with an `int` the compiler thinks that the type of the variable `value` is `int` and `json_object_getString(val)` returns `const char*`. So the compiler says:
`can not convert from const char* to int`.

Have you got any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: how is value defined? is it the `T &value` in the parameter list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you even using a template if you are going to do a switch statement of a bunch of if statements for each type? Your template instantiation will never compile if you want to treat every type as multiple types. This design is flawed but if you must then you can use specializations to accomplish something similar.

```
template<class T> void jsonParse(json_object* jobj, eParseWhat parseWhat, T &value) {
    static_assert(false); // not a handled type
}

template<> void jsonParse(json_object* jobj, eParseWhat parseWhat, int &value) {
    value = json_object_getInt(val);
}

template<> void jsonParse(json_object* jobj, eParseWhat parseWhat, std::string &value) {
    value = json_object_getString(val);
}
```

As GMan points out it is usually preferable to overload functions rather than specialize a function template. The equivalent using an overloaded function would be something like this:

```
void jsonParse(json_object* jobj, eParseWhat parseWhat, int &value) {
        value = json_object_getInt(val);
    }

void jsonParse(json_object* jobj, eParseWhat parseWhat, std::string &value) {
        value = json_object_getString(val);
    }
```

Comment: Better just to use overloads, then.

Comment: Correct GMan the template seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers guys!
I recognized that using a template in this case isn't a good solution...I think I will overload the function with the different types...and i will take a look at boost:any ;)

Comment: You can get started by reading this comparison of `boost::variant` to `boost::any` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you intend to write:

```
    if(parseWhat == PARSE_UID) {
        value = json_object_getInt(val);
    }
    else if(parseWhar == PARSE_EMAIL) {
        value = json_object_getString(val);
    }
```

On a sidenote: template usage in your example is quite strange and confusing to me. I'd rather use some kind of `Variant` class for this (one example is [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/libs/any/), but you can easily implement your own - it's a matter of two hours).

Comment: `boost::any` isn't a variant class, `boost::variant` is.

Comment: @GMan: I didn't use it, but the description says it IS a variant class

Comment: Boost.Any offers a dynamic variant, Boost.Variant offers a static variant. With the way the code is being used, I would agree with @GMan that a static variant is warranted here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile in any way, cause in that method T value can't be int and char* at the same time...

You try to cast differnt types (one is a int, on is a char) to a value (that isn't even defined) ;)

First you have to use:

```
json_object* obj = ...;
int uid = 0;

jsonParse<int>(obj,PARSE_UID,uid); //last parameter is int
```

or

```
jsonParse<string>(obj,PARSE_UID,whatever); //last parameter is string
```

But that don't work, as said before... you can't use a type in two diffrent ways in one template...

Sorry... :)